# MYSQL query creation

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a mysql query that will do the following:

For each record within Table 1, find a matching record in Table 2 where column A & B of Table 1 match column Y & Z of Table 2.

Once a match is found, grab column X value from Table 2 record and insert that value into column C of the original record in Table 1.

I hope that makes sense.

How the heck do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [multi-table update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html), just without modifying any columns from Table 2, as follows:

```
UPDATE Table1 T1, Table2 T2
SET T1.C = T2.X
WHERE T1.A = T2.Y AND T1.B = T2.Z;
```

Comment: Looks to have accomplished exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.a = table2.y AND table1.b = table2.z SET table1.c = table2.x;
```

Comment: It looks as if your solution may be the same as azemik's (which is the one I used).  So, I'm guessing this would have also accomplished my goals.  Thank you for your help.  I've marked this solution as having been helpful, since it also looks like a valid solution. EDIT: Actually, it looks like I don't have privileges enough to do that - sorry.